# Aligning two components horizontally in Angular9

Tags: css, layout, primeng, angular-components, angular9

I have two components. One is search form and one is search form result. On click of button in search form, search result component is displayed.
Currently it is coming vertically. What I want is to show the search result next to the search form (horizontally).

In search form html I have given bootstrap grid as 4 and in search result I have given as 8.

I tried to give common div class into global style.css and set it as `display: inline-block` but no luck.

My first component is a bootstrap form. My second component is a PrimeNG data table.

**What I have tried?**

```
Component 1 templateUrl : 'component1.html' > div classes to create a search form and parent div having test as class
Component 2 tempalteUrl : 'component2.html' > div classes to create a primeNG data table and div having test as class
Global style.css > .test {display: inline-block} so that I can align them horizontally.
```

**EDIT**

Above way I had tried which is not working properly. I am adding a sample output illustration which is coming right now.

[image]

**How I actually wanted it**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u need to add the width percentage so it would be ex: ‘ width: 19%; ‘